# python pandas - string matching

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas, type-conversion

I am trying to match a string value with a dataframe column1 value , based on the match I am feeding the column 2 value to a variable which I am further using in calculations :

```
#Val is a string
NewVal = df.loc[df['col1']== Val]['col2'].values
```

Even though the match exists , the above returns a null value .. I understand there might be a datatype mismatch since variable `val` is a string and `df['col1']` is an object data type , Is there anyway to convert the column to a string ? (I tried `df..astype(str)` and `df.astype(basestring)`.

What can I do to successfully match these strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through Pandas string functions ...

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Use the `contains` method (which even takes regular expresions). Something like this:

```
toUse = df['col1'].str.contains(Val)
valsIwant = df['col2'][toUse]
```

You will also find a lot of good string methods in that site.